# How would I assign the optimal weight matrix to combine the following moment conditions in MM?

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

The following information is given: Based on a sample x(n), with n = 1,..., 100 from the exponential distribution, we want to estimate lambda but the original data was lost; we only know that 38 observations are >= 1 and 11 observations are >= 2. Combining the information based on the 38 greater than or equal to 1 and the 11 greater than or equal to 2, what is the optimal weight matrix to combine the two moment conditions?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Jamie, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the wiki for the `[self-study]` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \sim \exp(\lambda)$, as in $f(x) = \lambda^{-1} \exp( -x/\lambda)$, define $x_1 = 1[x\ge1]$ and $x_2=1[x\ge2]$ where $1[\cdot]$ is the 0/1 indicator of the event in brackets. They are obviously correlated as $x_2=1$ implies $x_1=1$, although not vice versa. You are given the sample means of these variables. Compute their variances and covariances as a function of $\lambda$, and invert the matrix to get the weight matrix you need.

In this problem, you arrive at the continuous updating version of the GMM estimator in which the weight matrix explicitly depends on the unknown parameter. This is kinda cute.